# Resize and copy of c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

If I have for example array of pointers (which is full) with 5 elements and I want to insert another element at second position, I would have to allocate another array (with size+1), copy first element from an old array, insert new element, and then copy remaining elements. This application can't waste any space.
This is the code so far:

```
Sometype **newArray=new Sometype*[++Count];
size_t s=sizeof(Array);
memcpy(newArray,Array,s*position);
newArray[position]=new Sometype();
memcpy(newArray+position+1,Array+position,s*(Count-position-1));

delete [] Array;
Array=newArray;
```

Is there any more efficient method to do this thing because this is a bottleneck for my application?I'm new to c++ so I don't know any advanced stuff.
Could vector be used for this purpose?
I think I read somewhere that it takes double of previous used space when it's resizing.
Is this true or this behavior can be modified?

Comment: If you really do want to minimize memory use, go with std::vector as was suggested above.  It'll also clean up your code considerably.  If you want to avoid all the copying, go with std::list which will quickly insert without tons of copying but which will also use more memory.  Not sure you're saying its about memory use or avoiding the copying -- you said "can't waste any space" and "a bottleneck for my application" -- Not sure if you mean the copying speed is the bottleneck or the memory usage is.

Comment: @Nerdtron I have memory limit, but copying speed is the bottleneck

Comment: If the bottleneck is copying speed then maybe std::list is the answer then.  It uses a doubly-linked list, so you're going to have 2 pointers for every item in the list in memory overhead but inserting an element will be constant time, just a matter of adjusting a few pointers.

Comment: @Nerdtron: Insertion in a list is constant-time only if you already know the position (i.e. have an iterator at that position). If you need to locate the insertion position it's linear again, but with much worse cache behaviour than an array.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, good point.  if you don't have a pointer to the next or prev item where you're doing the insert then you would have to search for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't waste *any* space *and* you have to stick to sequential containers, then I'm afraid this is the most efficient way. But I still don't believe that you *can't* waste any space. If you can anticipate in advance that you will need to later add 5 more elements, then having your array resized from the beginning will prove much more effective. In any case, you should use vector to avoid this awful C-style code and be more clear with your intents. You might want to take a look at `std::vector<T>::reserve()` function. Whether or not vector takes double of previous when it's resizing is unspecified and varies across implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the standard containers `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map`